# Python Dataframe Get Substring

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have some dataframes where its id colum like

> A12-B-56
> E1234B115

It is always some letters and then several numbers, then -B- or B, and I want to keep substrings before '-B-' and 'B'.  One way that I came up with is using a for loop and re.split('(\d+)', some_text). Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: `df['column].str.replace('\-','',regex=True)`

Comment: @wwnde It does not solve my problem. I only need the first part, A12, of the data.

Comment: can you more clearly describe what the exact criteria for the match is? maybe provide some additional examples? is it always the first three characters? or always a letter and then variable number of numbers, and you want to split before the next non-numeric number? etc

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I edited my questions to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lookahead assertion to get all the alphanumerics from start that are followed by `B`. Would be wise to do this before you replace `-`. code below:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'column':['A12-B-56','A123B567']})

df= df.assign(column=(df['column'].str.replace('\-','', regex=True).str.extract('(^\w+(?=B))')))
```

As proposed by @mozway make it a one liner short and concise

```
df['column'].str.extract('(^\w+)-?B')
```

Comment: In one step `df['column'].str.extract('(^\w+)-?B')` ;)